# Do orchestral string instruments need a pause before con sordino?

Tags: notation, technique, composition, orchestral-strings

I’m a self-taught wannabe composer who’s playing with strings in Sibelius and I’m trying to learn the intricacies of writing for different techniques, such as *con sordino*, *sul pont.*, etc. My question is: In a passage where the strings change from natural/open to a technique that requires a physical modification to the instrument (such as installing a mute for *sordino*), must the composer write a pause/rest to give the players time to put the mute in place, or can the strings change technique fluidly with uninterrupted playing? And if there must be a break, how long should it be as a rule of thumb? A second? Five?

Here’s an image to illustrate the idea: A continuous passage …

[image: Violin passage with uninterrupted change to con sordino]

… vs. a break before the technique change:

[image: Violin passage with break before change to con sordino]

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: A string instrument requires the use of both hands to play "fluidly & uninterruptedly", and very few string players have a third hand with which to apply a mute while doing this.

Comment: In general (I know, a dangerous way to start a comment), a switch from unmuted to muted or vice versa only makes sense if there's a significant change in theme or pace of the music, in which case you can pretty much guarantee there's time for the players to adjust the mute.  If you simply want large dynamic change, that's what  "ff subito pp"  is for.  Just as Beethoven :-)

Comment: Fully agree with Carl Witthoft. Unlike with brass, the Sordino isn't that interesting for string instruments anyway: the small rubber ones that orchestral players generally use have very little effect on the sound – much less than the player can achieve with the bow alone – whereas the larger metal or wooden ones just give a pretty much “dead” sound which isn't very useful musically, only for practising. Usually, it's much more effective to specify _sul tasto_ or _dolce_. For quick, clearly noticeable change you may contrast that with _sul ponticello_, or _martellato_ etc..

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Pathetique's fourth mvt begs to differ. ff con sordini is indeed a very precise effect ;)

Comment: @leftaroundabout "the small rubber ones that orchestral players generally use have very little effect on the sound". I disagree. The effect is indeed less impactful than brasses (which is true of pretty much anything: brasses are more impactful, period) but **clearly** changes the color of the sound.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier it certainly changes the sound, but not in a clear but very subtle manner. Excellent for giving an entire piece an eerie or disillusioned mood, but not for effecting sharp contrasts within a movement. Indeed I believe a large part of the sordino's effect is how it affects how the musicians _feel their own playing_ – it gives them a sort of “lost in the fog” / “running against walls” feeling, and that in turn affects what they put again into the music.

Comment: Interesting! I stand by my point however, yes, it is a very clear effect. Maybe beginner musicians, or other people that don't know about it won't realize. As a profesionnal orchestral player, I can assure you no musicians I know do not realize when a violin sound is muted or not. On the other hand, I totally do not feel any differently when using a mute, and actually that would be counter productive as the mute is already there doing its effect. Adding more is not the intended effect. A forte with mute is exactly that, a forte with mute.

Comment: I agree, however, that sharp contrasts between ff and pp is not the intended use of mutes. That is indeed what dynamics are for.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I wouldn't say it's so much about “doing more” but _doing it differently_. A mute perhaps allows the player to play with rather _more_ force than they otherwise would, at any given dynamic level. I notice it most strongly when (cello) playing stuff in uncomfortably high positions, where my natural reflex is to “tip-toe” my way into the notes. A mute helps me a lot practising such stuff in a more confident manner. — OTOH: once, the first movement we did after a rehearsal break, I kept wondering what was wrong with my cello that made it feel so dull. Guess what it was?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier  I didn't intend to give the impression that switching mutes on or off was associated solely with dynamics, but rather a change in mood, theme, etc.  Also, as you certainly know,  different mutes can produce very different muted sounds -- not noticeable in an orchestra but certainly in chamber or solo music.

Comment: A composer should note that a string section applying mutes can often be noisy. Rubber mutes can squeak quite a bit when applied, especially hurriedly. String players know to apply the mutes at the first chance they get, so if you give them a multi-measure rest while other sections are playing loudly, they'll apply the mute during the rest and the squeaking will be covered. On the other hand, if you have them do it during two beats in an oboe solo, the solo will be covered by the sound of a basketball court full of Nikes.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For what it's worth, here's what Berlioz has to say in his *Treatise on Instrumentation*:

> The composer, when indicating the use of mutes in the middle of a piece (by the words *con sordini*), must not forget to allow sufficient time for putting them on.  He should provide a rest in the violins, equal in length to about two bars in 4-4 time, moderato.  The rest may be shorter when the words *senza sordini* indicate that the mutes are to be removed;  this can be done in much less time.

If you do need a transition to or from mutes during continuous playing, you could perhaps divide a section and have half the players start playing with mutes at the same time that the other half end an unmuted phrase.

Comment: I _thought_ there might be some written guidelines somewhere, but as always Google failed to find it for me. From what I gather from your and @alephzero’s reply below, a minimum of five–six seconds seems enough for expert players to slide a mute into position. At any rate, it’s clear you can’t just switch to playing _sordino_ in the midst of a frenzied sequence, so my question has been answered. Thanks.

Comment: Remember Berlioz was writing about 150-year-old mute designs that simply clipped on top of the bridge. He was right that *they* are quicker to remove than to put on (to remove it, just pull), but only if you don't care where the mute ended up afterwards, because it wasn't attached to the violin or anything else! If you need it quickly later, balancing a mute on your knee while playing isn't as easy as having it permanently attached to the strings behind the bridge. And balancing it on the music rest doesn't work if you need to turn a page.

Comment: @alephzero:  Fair enough;  I wasn't sure how much mute technology had changed since Berlioz's day.  But as a trombone player, I am all too familiar with the need to awkwardly balance a mute on my lap when a thoughtless composer doesn't give me enough time to remove it and put it down carefully.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert most modern mutes are moulded soft rubber, or plastic. In Berlioz's time they would have been made from wood,  usually ebony, and clip on top of the bridge, like a modern "practice mute". Violin mutes are too small to put on the floor and pick up quickly - the same size as an average coin.

Answer (score 12):

Orchestral string players often have mutes that are clipped onto the strings behind the bridge, so they are quick to apply and remove, and don't get lost. One type has a small "handle" to make it easier to apply quickly. Another type just pushes against the face of the bridge, instead of being clipped on top of it (which is a bit more fiddly to do).

It's not an instantaneous operation, but 5 seconds should be enough time for a professional standard player.

This video doesn't really show a "quick change," but it gives a some idea of what is involved - not much, after a bit of practise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Between you and Michael Seifert above, my question stands answered.